# No such file or directory in Heredoc, Bash

Tags: bash, heredoc

I am deeply confused by Bash's Heredoc construct behaviour.

Here is what I am doing:

```
#!/bin/bash
user="some_user"
server="some_server"
address="$user"@"$server"

printf -v user_q '%q' "$user"

function run {
    ssh "$address" /bin/bash "$@"
}

run << SSHCONNECTION1
    sudo dpkg-query -W -f='${Status}' nano 2>/dev/null | grep -c "ok installed" > /home/$user_q/check.txt

    softwareInstalled=$(cat /home/$user_q/check.txt)

SSHCONNECTION1
```

What I get is

> cat: /home/some_user/check.txt: No such file or directory

This is very bizarre, because the file exists if I was to connect using SSH and check the following path.

What am I doing wrong? File is not executable, just a text file. 
Thank you.

Comment: The `$(cat ...)` command is running locally.

Comment: btw, note the alternate answer I linked to in your former question (using `printf '%q ' "$@"` to generate an argv list, passing that on the command line to your remote shell, and then referring to items off it with `$1`, `$2`, etc; this is one of the scenarios it avoids).

Comment: ...though the caveat there is that the remote `/bin/sh` needs to be able to parse what `printf '%q'` generated, which might be a problem if it's not bash or ksh and you have unusual characters in your arguments.

Comment: Also, `softwareInstalled` only exists on the remote server; there is little point in defining it, then doing nothing with it in the remote script.

Comment: @chepner I am not showing the entire script, the variable is used later. Thanks

Comment: @Alex; *nod* -- the point was being well-made that it's a *remote* variable as opposed to a local one, though, and thus that its scope ends with the end of the heredoc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy correct, that is the intention. Thanks for checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `cat` to run remotely, rather than locally during the heredoc's evaluation, escape the `$` in the `$(...)`:

```
softwareInstalled=\$(cat /home/$user_q/check.txt)
```

Of course, this only has meaning if some other part of your remote script then refers to `"$softwareInstalled"` (or, since it's in an unquoted heredoc, `"\$softwareInstalled"`).

Comment: `$softwareInstalled` is used later on. Thank you, but why is cat executed locally? I thought the execution is sequential line by line?

Comment: @Alex, `$(cat ...)` is executed locally for the same reason that `$user_q` contains your local variable: Expansions are performed when generating text corresponding to the heredoc. If you didn't want that to happen you could quote your sigil (`<<'SSHCONNECTION1'`), but then other variables wouldn't be substituted either.

Comment: BTW, (while you've presumably figured this out by now) -- do be sure that the later part of your script in the heredoc is using `\$softwareInstalled`, so that it's remotely rather than locally evaluated. I've edited the answer to specify this as well.